# Postgresql sequential scan slow performance on 500 million rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I am trying to select all rows of a table containing ~500 million rows with Postgresql 11.

This is taking ~15 minutes on a VM with 32 CPU cores and 256GB of RAM and an SSD with up to ~200MB/s for read/write, which is much higher than I would expect when I see people selecting a million of rows in ~1s (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188407/effectively-handle-10-100-millions-row-table-of-unrelated-data), although they don't sort the rows.

The queries on this table will mostly consist of `SELECT` operations on 80% to 100% of the table, with filters on the datetime, where rows are sorted by datetime.

Here is the description of the table:

```
postgres=# \d+ ohlcv;
                                              Table "public.ohlcv"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
 datetime | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
 open     | real                        |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
 high     | real                        |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
 low      | real                        |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
 close    | real                        |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
 volume   | integer                     |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "brin_datetime" brin (datetime)
```

All the rows were added at once and the brin index was added after.

Here is the query, which seems to use 8 cpus instead of the 32 available:

```
postgres=# explain analyze
postgres-# select * from ohlcv order by datetime;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=20712603.78..96175039.28 rows=610230784 width=28) (actual time=175360.971..721544.003 rows=610230801 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 8
   Workers Launched: 8
   ->  Sort  (cost=20711603.64..20902300.76 rows=76278848 width=28) (actual time=125461.665..170299.327 rows=67803422 loops=9)
         Sort Key: datetime
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2429104kB
         Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2404680kB
         Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2406280kB
         Worker 2:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2656672kB
         Worker 3:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2635904kB
         Worker 4:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2637600kB
         Worker 5:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2643400kB
         Worker 6:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2437272kB
         Worker 7:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2439272kB
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ohlcv  (cost=0.00..5249780.48 rows=76278848 width=28) (actual time=0.049..42506.065 rows=67803422 loops=9)
 Planning Time: 0.566 ms
 Execution Time: 1059414.396 ms
(17 rows)
```

Here is the configuration of postgres:

```
 check_function_bodies                  | on                                       | Check function bodies during CREATE FUNCTION.
 checkpoint_completion_target           | 0.5                                      | Time spent flushing dirty buffers during checkpoint, as fraction of checkpoint interval.
 checkpoint_flush_after                 | 256kB                                    | Number of pages after which previously performed writes are flushed to disk.
 checkpoint_timeout                     | 5min                                     | Sets the maximum time between automatic WAL checkpoints.
 checkpoint_warning                     | 30s                                      | Enables warnings if checkpoint segments are filled more frequently than this.
 client_encoding                        | UTF8                                     | Sets the client's character set encoding.
 client_min_messages                    | notice                                   | Sets the message levels that are sent to the client.
 cluster_name                           |                                          | Sets the name of the cluster, which is included in the process title.
 commit_delay                           | 0                                        | Sets the delay in microseconds between transaction commit and flushing WAL to disk.
 commit_siblings                        | 5                                        | Sets the minimum concurrent open transactions before performing commit_delay.
 config_file                            | /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf | Sets the server's main configuration file.
 constraint_exclusion                   | partition                                | Enables the planner to use constraints to optimize queries.
 cpu_index_tuple_cost                   | 0.005                                    | Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of processing each index entry during an index scan.
 cpu_operator_cost                      | 0.0025                                   | Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of processing each operator or function call.
 cpu_tuple_cost                         | 0.01                                     | Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of processing each tuple (row).
 cursor_tuple_fraction                  | 0.1                                      | Sets the planner's estimate of the fraction of a cursor's rows that will be retrieved.
 data_checksums                         | off                                      | Shows whether data checksums are turned on for this cluster.
 data_directory                         | /var/lib/postgresql/data                 | Sets the server's data directory.
 data_directory_mode                    | 0700                                     | Mode of the data directory.
 data_sync_retry                        | off                                      | Whether to continue running after a failure to sync data files.
 DateStyle                              | ISO, MDY                                 | Sets the display format for date and time values.
 db_user_namespace                      | off                                      | Enables per-database user names.
 deadlock_timeout                       | 1s                                       | Sets the time to wait on a lock before checking for deadlock.
 debug_assertions                       | off                                      | Shows whether the running server has assertion checks enabled.
 debug_pretty_print                     | on                                       | Indents parse and plan tree displays.
 debug_print_parse                      | off                                      | Logs each query's parse tree.
 debug_print_plan                       | off                                      | Logs each query's execution plan.
 debug_print_rewritten                  | off                                      | Logs each query's rewritten parse tree.
 default_statistics_target              | 100                                      | Sets the default statistics target.
 default_tablespace                     |                                          | Sets the default tablespace to create tables and indexes in.
 default_text_search_config             | pg_catalog.english                       | Sets default text search configuration.
 default_transaction_deferrable         | off                                      | Sets the default deferrable status of new transactions.
 default_transaction_isolation          | read committed                           | Sets the transaction isolation level of each new transaction.
 default_transaction_read_only          | off                                      | Sets the default read-only status of new transactions.
 default_with_oids                      | off                                      | Create new tables with OIDs by default.
 dynamic_library_path                   | $libdir                                  | Sets the path for dynamically loadable modules.
 dynamic_shared_memory_type             | posix                                    | Selects the dynamic shared memory implementation used.
 effective_cache_size                   | 4GB                                      | Sets the planner's assumption about the total size of the data caches.
 effective_io_concurrency               | 1                                        | Number of simultaneous requests that can be handled efficiently by the disk subsystem.
 enable_bitmapscan                      | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of bitmap-scan plans.
 enable_gathermerge                     | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of gather merge plans.
 enable_hashagg                         | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of hashed aggregation plans.
 enable_hashjoin                        | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of hash join plans.
 enable_indexonlyscan                   | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of index-only-scan plans.
 enable_indexscan                       | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of index-scan plans.
 enable_material                        | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of materialization.
 enable_mergejoin                       | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of merge join plans.
 enable_nestloop                        | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of nested-loop join plans.
 enable_parallel_append                 | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of parallel append plans.
 enable_parallel_hash                   | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of parallel hash plans.
 enable_partition_pruning               | on                                       | Enable plan-time and run-time partition pruning.
 enable_partitionwise_aggregate         | off                                      | Enables partitionwise aggregation and grouping.
 enable_partitionwise_join              | off                                      | Enables partitionwise join.
 enable_seqscan                         | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of sequential-scan plans.
 enable_sort                            | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of explicit sort steps.
 enable_tidscan                         | on                                       | Enables the planner's use of TID scan plans.
 escape_string_warning                  | on                                       | Warn about backslash escapes in ordinary string literals.
 event_source                           | PostgreSQL                               | Sets the application name used to identify PostgreSQL messages in the event log.
 exit_on_error                          | off                                      | Terminate session on any error.
 external_pid_file                      |                                          | Writes the postmaster PID to the specified file.
 extra_float_digits                     | 0                                        | Sets the number of digits displayed for floating-point values.
 force_parallel_mode                    | off                                      | Forces use of parallel query facilities.
 from_collapse_limit                    | 8                                        | Sets the FROM-list size beyond which subqueries are not collapsed.
 fsync                                  | on                                       | Forces synchronization of updates to disk.
 full_page_writes                       | on                                       | Writes full pages to WAL when first modified after a checkpoint.
 geqo                                   | on                                       | Enables genetic query optimization.
 geqo_effort                            | 5                                        | GEQO: effort is used to set the default for other GEQO parameters.
 geqo_generations                       | 0                                        | GEQO: number of iterations of the algorithm.
 geqo_pool_size                         | 0                                        | GEQO: number of individuals in the population.
 geqo_seed                              | 0                                        | GEQO: seed for random path selection.
 geqo_selection_bias                    | 2                                        | GEQO: selective pressure within the population.
 geqo_threshold                         | 12                                       | Sets the threshold of FROM items beyond which GEQO is used.
 gin_fuzzy_search_limit                 | 0                                        | Sets the maximum allowed result for exact search by GIN.
 gin_pending_list_limit                 | 4MB                                      | Sets the maximum size of the pending list for GIN index.
 hba_file                               | /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf     | Sets the server's "hba" configuration file.
 hot_standby                            | on                                       | Allows connections and queries during recovery.
 hot_standby_feedback                   | off                                      | Allows feedback from a hot standby to the primary that will avoid query conflicts.
 huge_pages                             | try                                      | Use of huge pages on Linux or Windows.
 ident_file                             | /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_ident.conf   | Sets the server's "ident" configuration file.
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout    | 0                                        | Sets the maximum allowed duration of any idling transaction.
 ignore_checksum_failure                | off                                      | Continues processing after a checksum failure.
 ignore_system_indexes                  | off                                      | Disables reading from system indexes.
 integer_datetimes                      | on                                       | Datetimes are integer based.
 IntervalStyle                          | postgres                                 | Sets the display format for interval values.
 jit                                    | off                                      | Allow JIT compilation.
 jit_above_cost                         | 100000                                   | Perform JIT compilation if query is more expensive.
 jit_debugging_support                  | off                                      | Register JIT compiled function with debugger.
 jit_dump_bitcode                       | off                                      | Write out LLVM bitcode to facilitate JIT debugging.
 jit_expressions                        | on                                       | Allow JIT compilation of expressions.
 jit_inline_above_cost                  | 500000                                   | Perform JIT inlining if query is more expensive.
 jit_optimize_above_cost                | 500000                                   | Optimize JITed functions if query is more expensive.
 jit_profiling_support                  | off                                      | Register JIT compiled function with perf profiler.
 jit_provider                           | llvmjit                                  | JIT provider to use.
 jit_tuple_deforming                    | on                                       | Allow JIT compilation of tuple deforming.
 join_collapse_limit                    | 8                                        | Sets the FROM-list size beyond which JOIN constructs are not flattened.
 krb_caseins_users                      | off                                      | Sets whether Kerberos and GSSAPI user names should be treated as case-insensitive.
 krb_server_keyfile                     | FILE:/etc/postgresql-common/krb5.keytab  | Sets the location of the Kerberos server key file.
 lc_collate                             | en_US.utf8                               | Shows the collation order locale.
 lc_ctype                               | en_US.utf8                               | Shows the character classification and case conversion locale.
 lc_messages                            | en_US.utf8                               | Sets the language in which messages are displayed.
 lc_monetary                            | en_US.utf8                               | Sets the locale for formatting monetary amounts.
 lc_numeric                             | en_US.utf8                               | Sets the locale for formatting numbers.
 lc_time                                | en_US.utf8                               | Sets the locale for formatting date and time values.
 listen_addresses                       | *                                        | Sets the host name or IP address(es) to listen to.
 lo_compat_privileges                   | off                                      | Enables backward compatibility mode for privilege checks on large objects.
 local_preload_libraries                |                                          | Lists unprivileged shared libraries to preload into each backend.
 lock_timeout                           | 0                                        | Sets the maximum allowed duration of any wait for a lock.
 log_autovacuum_min_duration            | -1                                       | Sets the minimum execution time above which autovacuum actions will be logged.
 log_checkpoints                        | off                                      | Logs each checkpoint.
 log_connections                        | off                                      | Logs each successful connection.
 log_destination                        | stderr                                   | Sets the destination for server log output.
 log_directory                          | log                                      | Sets the destination directory for log files.
 log_disconnections                     | off                                      | Logs end of a session, including duration.
 log_duration                           | off                                      | Logs the duration of each completed SQL statement.
 log_error_verbosity                    | default                                  | Sets the verbosity of logged messages.
 log_executor_stats                     | off                                      | Writes executor performance statistics to the server log.
 log_file_mode                          | 0600                                     | Sets the file permissions for log files.
 log_filename                           | postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log           | Sets the file name pattern for log files.
 log_hostname                           | off                                      | Logs the host name in the connection logs.
 log_line_prefix                        | %m [%p]                                  | Controls information prefixed to each log line.
 log_lock_waits                         | off                                      | Logs long lock waits.
 log_min_duration_statement             | -1                                       | Sets the minimum execution time above which statements will be logged.
 log_min_error_statement                | error                                    | Causes all statements generating error at or above this level to be logged.
 log_min_messages                       | warning                                  | Sets the message levels that are logged.
 log_parser_stats                       | off                                      | Writes parser performance statistics to the server log.
 log_planner_stats                      | off                                      | Writes planner performance statistics to the server log.
 log_replication_commands               | off                                      | Logs each replication command.
 log_rotation_age                       | 1d                                       | Automatic log file rotation will occur after N minutes.
 log_rotation_size                      | 10MB                                     | Automatic log file rotation will occur after N kilobytes.
 log_statement                          | none                                     | Sets the type of statements logged.
 log_statement_stats                    | off                                      | Writes cumulative performance statistics to the server log.
 log_temp_files                         | -1                                       | Log the use of temporary files larger than this number of kilobytes.
 log_timezone                           | UTC                                      | Sets the time zone to use in log messages.
 log_truncate_on_rotation               | off                                      | Truncate existing log files of same name during log rotation.
 logging_collector                      | off                                      | Start a subprocess to capture stderr output and/or csvlogs into log files.
 maintenance_work_mem                   | 64MB                                     | Sets the maximum memory to be used for maintenance operations.
 max_connections                        | 100                                      | Sets the maximum number of concurrent connections.
 max_files_per_process                  | 1000                                     | Sets the maximum number of simultaneously open files for each server process.
 max_function_args                      | 100                                      | Shows the maximum number of function arguments.
 max_identifier_length                  | 63                                       | Shows the maximum identifier length.
 max_index_keys                         | 32                                       | Shows the maximum number of index keys.
 max_locks_per_transaction              | 64                                       | Sets the maximum number of locks per transaction.
 max_logical_replication_workers        | 4                                        | Maximum number of logical replication worker processes.
 max_parallel_maintenance_workers       | 2                                        | Sets the maximum number of parallel processes per maintenance operation.
 max_parallel_workers                   | 32                                       | Sets the maximum number of parallel workers that can be active at one time.
 max_parallel_workers_per_gather        | 32                                       | Sets the maximum number of parallel processes per executor node.
 max_pred_locks_per_page                | 2                                        | Sets the maximum number of predicate-locked tuples per page.
 max_pred_locks_per_relation            | -2                                       | Sets the maximum number of predicate-locked pages and tuples per relation.
 max_pred_locks_per_transaction         | 64                                       | Sets the maximum number of predicate locks per transaction.
 max_prepared_transactions              | 0                                        | Sets the maximum number of simultaneously prepared transactions.
 max_replication_slots                  | 10                                       | Sets the maximum number of simultaneously defined replication slots.
 max_stack_depth                        | 2MB                                      | Sets the maximum stack depth, in kilobytes.
 max_standby_archive_delay              | 30s                                      | Sets the maximum delay before canceling queries when a hot standby server is processing archived WAL data.
 max_standby_streaming_delay            | 30s                                      | Sets the maximum delay before canceling queries when a hot standby server is processing streamed WAL data.
 max_sync_workers_per_subscription      | 2                                        | Maximum number of table synchronization workers per subscription.
 max_wal_senders                        | 10                                       | Sets the maximum number of simultaneously running WAL sender processes.
 max_wal_size                           | 1GB                                      | Sets the WAL size that triggers a checkpoint.
 max_worker_processes                   | 32                                       | Maximum number of concurrent worker processes.
 min_parallel_index_scan_size           | 512kB                                    | Sets the minimum amount of index data for a parallel scan.
 min_parallel_table_scan_size           | 8MB                                      | Sets the minimum amount of table data for a parallel scan.
 min_wal_size                           | 80MB                                     | Sets the minimum size to shrink the WAL to.
 old_snapshot_threshold                 | -1                                       | Time before a snapshot is too old to read pages changed after the snapshot was taken.
 operator_precedence_warning            | off                                      | Emit a warning for constructs that changed meaning since PostgreSQL 9.4.
 parallel_leader_participation          | on                                       | Controls whether Gather and Gather Merge also run subplans.
 parallel_setup_cost                    | 1000                                     | Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of starting up worker processes for parallel query.
 parallel_tuple_cost                    | 0.1                                      | Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of passing each tuple (row) from worker to master backend.
 password_encryption                    | md5                                      | Encrypt passwords.
 port                                   | 5432                                     | Sets the TCP port the server listens on.
 post_auth_delay                        | 0                                        | Waits N seconds on connection startup after authentication.
 pre_auth_delay                         | 0                                        | Waits N seconds on connection startup before authentication.
 quote_all_identifiers                  | off                                      | When generating SQL fragments, quote all identifiers.
 random_page_cost                       | 4                                        | Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of a nonsequentially fetched disk page.
 restart_after_crash                    | on                                       | Reinitialize server after backend crash.
 row_security                           | on                                       | Enable row security.
 search_path                            | "$user", public                          | Sets the schema search order for names that are not schema-qualified.
 segment_size                           | 1GB                                      | Shows the number of pages per disk file.
 seq_page_cost                          | 1   
 work_mem                               | 4MB                                      | Sets the maximum memory to be used for query workspaces.
```

Is it possible to lower the execution time to a few minutes or less or is it the expected execution time ?

Comment: What is work_mem set to?  It looks like it could use an increase to avoid those external sorts.

Comment: you could try to increase `effective_io_concurrency` maybe it will then use more parallel threads. What kind of harddisk does the system have?

Comment: work_mem is set to 4MB, the machine has an SSD with ~200MB/s for read/write, I updated the post

Comment: Based on the explain analyze output, it looks like a `work_mem` of 3GB should keep everything from spilling to disk. If you up `effective_io_concurrency`, too, you should be able to get away with a lower `work_mem`.

Comment: I'll add that many of your other config settings seem mistuned. The `seq_page_cost` and `random_page_cost` should be closer together if everything's on SSD. Similarly, the `effective_cache_size` should be set to at least half your RAM (assuming nothing else is running on the machine, etc).

Comment: postgres -c 'max_worker_processes=32' -c 'max_parallel_workers_per_gather=32' -c 'max_parallel_workers=32' -c 'shared_buffers=4GB' -c 'effective_io_concurrency=100' -c 'work_mem=3GB' -c 'random_page_cost=2' -c 'effective_cache_size=128GB' gets the execution time to 914523.648 ms, which is not that much better, it is still using 8 workers and for most of the time only 1 cpu is at 100%, @jmelesky disk access remains the same (2551840kB)

Comment: I don’t know what limits Postgres parallelity in this case however it is unlikely that more than 8 external sorts in parallel will do you any good.

Comment: BRIN is an efficient Index if you search for small slices, but if you frequently select 80% and need order by this key, maybe a (even covering?k btree index might be better after all. Did you try that?

Comment: I have tried replacing the brin index by a binary tree and performances are similar, I also tried adding a CLUSTER on this index hoping to reduce the sort time but it didn't change the performances either

Answer (score 10):

There are only few things that will help with this query:

- The actual scanning doesn't seem to be the problem (it took 42 seconds), but if the table could be kept in RAM, it might be faster.
- Your main problem is the sort, which PostgreSQL already parallelizes.

  There are a few things you could tune:

  - Increase `work_mem` as much as possible, which will make the sort faster.
  - Increase `max_worker_processes` (this will require a restart), `max_parallel_workers` and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` so that more cores can be used for the query.

    PostgreSQL has an internal logic to calculate the maximum number of parallel workers it is ready to use for a table: it will consider as many parallel workers as

    log<sub>3</sub>(table size / `min_parallel_table_scan_size`)

    You can force it to use more processes than that with:

    ```
    ALTER TABLE ohlcv SET (parallel_workers = 20);
    ```

    But `max_parallel_workers` still is the upper limit.

If there are no deletes and updates on the table, and the data is inserted in sort order, you could get away with just omitting the `ORDER BY` clause, provided you set `synchronize_seqscans = off`.

Comment: `max_worker_processes`, `max_parallel_workers` and  `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` are already set to 32. I think the question is why Postgres only uses 8 workers instead of using all possible ones?

Comment: I have added some about this to the answer. Use the `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Using the `ALTER` indeed allowed postgres to use more core for the first few minutes but most of the time is still spent with 1 cpu at 100%, overall the performances are similar (~15mn), I also adjusted `work_mem` to 8GB. Is postgres (or relationnal db in general) really suited for this kind of request that always returns millions of rows in the same order ? Is there any way to ensure the rows of this table are stored in a sorted and contiguous way on the disk to get better performances ? I though CLUSTER would do that but the sort still takes as much time as without it

Comment: If you run this query often, I wonder why. Why not only get the latest rows? You'd be better off with a database that supports "index organized tables" or "clustering indexes" or however they choose to call the feature. Are the rows inserted in sort order? Are they ever modified?

Comment: They're inserted in sort order and are never updated, new records will be appended. We need all/most of the rows because the logic that manipulates this data is changing every time as its a research project, we can't just pick the latest rows and update some statistics. About clustering indexes, isn't it what the CLUSTER command does ?

Comment: A clustered table doesn't maintain the ordering, it "rots" as data modifications happen, But if your table is only inserted in sort order, you could be much faster just without the `ORDER BY`. See my updated answer.